# Printing BST in directory listing format

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I've this project to print a `Binary Search Tree` in these Formats (Pre-order, In-order, Post-order, and finally  directory listing format) 
I got them all working fine, except the  directory listing format, I didn't know how to print BST in this format, please See the pic I attached.

I'd very appreciate it if someone can help..

this is my method of printing

```
void preOrder(Node node)
 {
     if (node != null)
     {
         System.out.print(node.key + " ");
         preOrder(node.left);
         preOrder(node.right);
     }
 }`
 tree.preOrder(tree.root);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Level orer traversal . Psuedo algorithm is this:
initialize an empty queue.

> Use recursion from root
>
> Insert first root node in queue.print the node value
>
> If node has any left , insert left in queue
>
> If node has any right , insert right in queue,
>
> On checking for both insert a delimiter e.g '\0'.
>    again check if the queue is empty
>
> if empty stop recursion
>
> If not again go  back to step 1.

Thats how you can print directory listing format.

Follow this link for further understanding.
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-order-tree-traversal/